# ConTeXt - indented table, but horizontal rules go to left margin

Tags: tables, context

This will be my last ConTeXt question for a little while...I've set up

```
\setuptabulate[indenting=yes,margin=40pt]
```

This works only to the extent that the table cells are indented appropriately - but the horizontal rules stretch all the way to the left margin.  How do I set up a table to be indented properly - including its horizontal lines?

Here's a minimal example (without changing the table margin):

```
\setupindenting[20pt, yes]
\setuptabulate[indenting=yes]

\starttext
The following is a table for which the horizontal lines are wrong.
\starttabulate[|c|c|]
\HL
\NC Col 1 \NC Col 2 \NC\NR
\HL
\NC 1 \NC 2 \AR
\NC 3 \NC 3 \AR
\HL
\stoptabulate
See what I mean?

\stoptext
```

If you bung this through `texexec` you'll see that the lines of text are indented, but that the horizontal lines in the table aren't.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer would be: use `\startnarrower` ... `\stopnarrower`, but that does not work either. This setup produces the desired output (but I will point Hans to this example):

```
\setupindenting[20pt, yes]
\setupnarrower [left=20pt]

\starttext
The following is a table for which the horizontal lines are wrong. Bla
\startnarrower[left]
\startframedtext[frame=off,offset=overlay]
\starttabulate[|c|c|]
\HL
\NC Col 1 \NC Col 2 \NC\NR
\HL
\NC 1 \NC 2 \AR
\NC 3 \NC 3 \AR
\HL
\stoptabulate
\stopframedtext
\stopnarrower
See what I mean?

\stoptext
```

Comment: Tried that - made absolutely no difference.  Do I have to set up first with setupnarrower?  

Actually, if I include the line `setupnarrower[middle=6cm]` in the preamble, and then use \startnarrower ... \stopnarrower the table is positioned in the middle - but the lines *still* extend all the way to the left margin.

Comment: Arrgh - this is a right royal pain.  I simply *cannot* get my simple table, including its horizontal and vertical rules, moved away from the left margin. I've tried innumerable combinations of settings, with both table and tabulate, all to no avail.  This is a very simple table... but its positioning is giving me grief!

Comment: answer adjusted

Comment: Woo hoo - that works perfectly!  Thank you **very** much.  I wonder why it's so complicated, though?  I can move other things around very easily just by playing with margins: itemized lists, formulas etc - why not tables?

Comment: @Alasdair: the same should have worked for tables, but it appears broken/bugged. That's why I said I would alert Hans on this problem.

Comment: Oh I see - well thanks again! 

If you'd like me to test-drive any new amendments, let me know.

Comment: @Alasdair: Since you seem happy with this answer, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count. This shows that answer helped you, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).